# How to print this pyramid pattern up side down?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am trying to print below pyramid pattern. But not clicking how to build logic for it ?

**Pattern :**

```
5 4 3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
    3 2 1 
      2 1
        1
```

I have tried this code seems like this is not a right approach to get it.Any solution is appreciated

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
cnt=0
var = np.arange(1,n+1)
for row in range(1,n+1):
  print(var[::-1][cnt:])
  cnt= cnt + 1
```

**Output of above pattern:**

```
[5 4 3 2 1]
[4 3 2 1]
[3 2 1]
[2 1]
[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need/want to use numpy?

This is easily achievable using pure python. The logic is to add spaces on the left to pad (you could also use string functions like `rjust`):

```
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    print('  '*i + ' '.join(map(str, range(n-i, 0, -1))))
```

output:

```
5 4 3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
    3 2 1
      2 1
        1
```

*NB. if you have double digits, you should use `rjust`*:

```
n = 15
L = 0
for i in range(n):
    s = ' '.join(map(str, range(n-i, 0, -1)))
    L = max(L, len(s))
    print(s.rjust(L))
```

output:

```
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
      13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
         12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
            11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
               10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                      7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                        6 5 4 3 2 1
                          5 4 3 2 1
                            4 3 2 1
                              3 2 1
                                2 1
                                  1
```

Comment: can you elaborate what that join something doing

Comment: @hives47801 https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join

Comment: @hives47801 `join` is making a string separated by a separator out of elements of an iterable: `'-'.join(['A', 'B', 'C'])` is giving `'A-B-C'`

Comment: @mozway : Do you have any other approach apart from join method

Comment: @hives47801 you can use nested loops with `print` and `end=' '`, but this is not as nice. Just use `join`, it's a standard method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to reduce overall complexity

```
def pyramid(height):
   L = 0
   for i in range(height):
     s = ' '.join(map(str, range(height-i, 0, -1)))
     L = max(L, len(s))
     print(s.rjust(L))
height = int(input('Enter the height of the Pyramid : '))
pyramid(height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any solution? Ok:

```
>>> print("\n".join([ "{:>10}".format(" ".join([ str(x) for x in range(n,0,-1) ])) for n in range(5,0,-1) ]))
 5 4 3 2 1
   4 3 2 1
     3 2 1
       2 1
         1
```